# Postgres server does not support SSL, but SSL was required - CircleCI

Tags: django, postgresql, circleci

I'm creating a build-test-deploy pipeline using CircleCI for a Django application.

With `image: circleci/postgres:13.1`, the build fails while executing tests with:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: server does not support SSL, but SSL was required
...
...
django.db.utils.OperationalError: server does not support SSL, but SSL was required
```

(Complete traceback [here)](https://pastebin.com/xC1fBED3)

As a workaround, I'm using [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/nimbustech/postgres-ssl/) image, which has Postgres with SSL certificate.

(Complete `config.yml` [here](https://pastebin.com/hm7P43w8))

Is there a better way to this? Possibly with a CircleCI container image of more recent versions of postgres?

I haven't found anything in the CircleCI documentation regarding this.

Comment: Is that the yml that does work, or the one that doesn't?

Comment: The current `.yml` file works. If I swap lines 22 and 23, it doesn't.

Comment: Does your test use the DATABASE_URL from the config.yml for connecting?  Or does it have its own connection string?

Comment: The tests do not have their own connection string, they are using DATABASE_URL from `config.yml`.